# Why does it gives me this error? Python parser

Tags: parsing, ply

I'm developing a parser with ply. I have this parser rules:

```
def p_maint(p):
    'maint : PROGRAMA ID declaraciones'

def p_declaraciones(p):
    '''declaraciones : vacio
                     | declaraciones
                     | tipo ID definicion_vector ";"'''

def p_tipo(p):
    '''tipo : ENTERO
            | FLOTANTE
            | CHAR'''

def p_definicion_vector(p):
    '''definicion_vector : vacio 
                         | "[" CTE_ENTERO "]" '''


def p_vacio(p):
    'vacio : '
```

But it gives me a warning:

```
WARNING: 1 reduce/reduce conflict
WARNING: reduce/reduce conflict in state 8 resolved using rule (maint -> PROGRAMA ID declaraciones)
WARNING: rejected rule (declaraciones -> declaraciones) in state 8
WARNING: Rule (declaraciones -> declaraciones) is never reduced
```

How can I remove this errors?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the production `declaraciones -> declaraciones`, which is pointless. (It doesn't enlarge the language, and it makes the grammar ambiguous.)

My guess is, you meant to join two right-hand sides:

    `'''declaraciones : vacio
                     | declaraciones tipo ID definicion_vector ";"'''`